# I'm trying to remove transforms if my image is an svg? Any tips or advice would be great

Tags: templating, image-transforms, svg

```
 {% for icon in icons %}
                    {% set image = icon.icon.one() ?? null %}
                    {% if image %}
                        <div class="c c-md-6 c-lg-6">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="image">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="{{ image.getUrl('medium') }}" sizes="100vw" srcset="{{ image.getUrl('small') }} 320w, {{ image.getUrl('medium') }} 640w" alt="{{ image.title }}">
                                        <figcaption>{{ icon.title }}</figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if image.extension == 'svg' %}
  <img src="{{ image.url }}" ... />
{% else %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```